# file Columns not append correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I try to append below 2 files' data.  But the column "ytd" is appended in different column. And the columns reorder by alphabet.  Would appreciate some guidance on how to keep the columns order as the original file and make the ytd column of the 2 files together. Many thanks

My code is as below:

```
dfaq=pd.read_csv('aq2.csv')
dfmg1=pd.read_csv('test10320_2.csv')
dfaq1=dfmg1.append(dfaq, ignore_index=True)
```

**aq.csv**
[image]

**mg10320.csv**
[image]

** incorrect Result**
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes on the `ytd` column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)